# Escaping '{' and '}' in regex for C

Tags: c, regex, glibc

I would like to use the following regex `\{.+\}` in C. For example, `{HELLO}` would be valid but `HELLO}2`, `{HELLO` and `HELLO` would not.

I am making use of the POSIX regex library regex.h.

However, I am getting a regcomp error 13 when inputting `"\\{.+\\}"`, and `"\{.+\}"` is giving me an *unknown escape sequence warning*.

```
#include <regex.h>

int main()
{
    regex_t regex_enclosed;
    char* pattern_enclosed = "\\{.+\\}";

    // regex is not compiling but returning error code 13
    regcomp(&regex_enclosed, pattern_enclosed, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way around this? As if I don't escape the `{` and `}`, the pattern isn't compiled correctly.

Comment: Please post [mcve] so we can copy compile and see the errors ourselves.

Comment: @EugeneSh. edited

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to compile extended regular expressions. Basic regular expressions are not very intuitive and mostly obsolete. Furthermore, you want the shortest match to only match `{HOME}` in `"{HOME}/{DATE}"`:

```
regex_t regex_enclosed;
const char *pattern_enclosed = "\\{[^}]+\\}";  // can also use "[{][^}]+[}]"
int res = regcomp(&regex_enclosed, pattern_enclosed, REG_EXTENDED);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! super helpful and it worked now :) And yes, I also want the regex to match `{HOME}` in your example

Answer (score 1):

Without `REG_EXTENDED`, you are using POSIX BRE. You can still go with the POSIX BRE, just:

- Do not escape braces
- Use Kleene star `*` instead of `+` (`+` matches `+` in POSIX BRE)
- But use negated bracket expression to match text between braces.

Use

```cpp
regex_t regex_enclosed;
const char *pattern_enclosed = "{[^{}]*}";
int res = regcomp(&regex_enclosed, pattern_enclosed, 0);
```

**EXPLANATION**

```c
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}]*                   any character except: '{', '}' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }                        '}'
```